# Mongodb return Error : $cursor stage :: caused by :: operation was interrupted

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-4.0

In recently, i meet a problem with mongodb. After i surveyed on google, there is no good result unfortunately. So i really wish anyone could answer it.

As title, there is a kind of error message in my mongo.log. The error 
 occasionally occurs while i query which using aggregate with `$group` on secondary member. And i found that the error usually happens with the queried data is more lager than others.

The specification of vm machine is following,

- cpu core : 16
- ram : 64 gb
- disk : 500gb

> Error Message :     aggregate { aggregate: "AAA", pipeline: [ {
>   $match: { _id: { $gte: ObjectId('5cdd97100000000000000000'), $lt:
>   ObjectId('5cdda5200000000000000000') } } }, { $group: { _id: "$gtn",
>   pid: { $first: "$pid" }, oid: { $first: "$oid" } } } ], allowDiskUse:
>   true, cursor: {}, lsid: { id:
>   UUID("f57cce95-3b14-4467-8c10-853b8595ffe1") }, $clusterTime: {
>   clusterTime: Timestamp(1558036863, 4160), signature: { hash:
>   BinData(0, 7B2CC773CD95E611B6466D84CD39CB2CF48E1773), keyId:
>   6665898640503996417 } }, $db: "db1", $readPreference: { mode:
>   "secondary" } } planSummary: IXSCAN { _id: 1 } numYields:71781 ok:0
>   errMsg:"Error in $cursor stage :: caused by :: operation was
>   interrupted" errName:CursorKilled errCode:237 reslen:277 locks:{
>   Global: { acquireCount: { r: 72599 } }, Database: { acquireCount: { r:
>   72598 } }, Collection: { acquireCount: { r: 72598 } } }
>   protocol:op_msg 101051ms

Thank you for patient.